# Переписать код на СИ из for у while и do while

Tags: c, for, while

Можете переписать код из for у while и do while? Я пыталась сделать но у меня пропускается q1 и другие значения.
Вот мой for

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int t,fact=1,k;
    float y = 0,x,sum = 0;
    printf("\nEnter x= ");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    if ((x>-2)&&(x<2)) {
         for(k=1;k>0;k++) {
            for(t=1;t<=k+1;t++){
                fact=fact*t;
            }
             sum=(pow(-1,k)*pow(x,2*k+1))/((2*k-1)*fact);
            printf ("\n q[%d]=%f",k,sum);
             if (fabs(sum)<0.0001) { 
               printf ("\nbreaks on k=%d",k);
               break;
             }
            y=y+sum;
        }
    
    printf("\nThe sum of the members of the series=%f",y);
    printf("\nNumber of terms:%d",k);
    }
    else printf("\nError: you can enter -2<x<2");

    return 0;
}
```

Вот мой while который не получился

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int t = 1,fact=1;
    float y,x,sum, k=1;
    printf("\nEnter x= ");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    if ((x>-2)&&(x<2)) {
         while(k>0) {
             k++;
             
            while(t<=k+1){
                t++;
                fact=fact*t;
            }
             sum=(pow(-1,k)*pow(x,2*k+1))/((2*k-1)*fact);
            printf ("\n q[%f]=%f",k,sum);
             if (fabs(sum)<0.0001) { 
               printf ("\nbreaks on k=%d",k);
               break;
             }
            y=y+sum;
        }
    
    printf("\nThe sum of the members of the series=%f",y);
    printf("\nNumber of terms:%d",k);
    }
    else printf("\nError: you can enter -2<x<2");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while (true) {
        //k++;
        t = 1;
        while (t <= k + 1) {
            fact = fact * t;
            t++;
        }
        ...
        k++;
    }
```